# How to set up googletest on Windows with CLion

Tags: windows, cmake, googletest, clion

I have to use googletest on Windows with CLion for the first time, I tried to follow some guides, also from the official site of CLion, but I am not able to run googletest on my project.
[My files are organised like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS6gq.jpg), the blue underlined CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(provaQT)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets")

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

add_subdirectory(tests)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Subject.h Observer.h Resource.cpp Resource.h 
MainWindow.cpp MainWindow.h tests/ResourceTests.cpp)
add_executable(provaQT main.cpp)
add_library(core ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(core Qt5::Widgets)
target_link_libraries(provaQT core)
```

The other CMakeLists.txt inside the folder "tests" contains:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

add_subdirectory(./lib/googletest)
set(gtest_SOURCE_DIR ./lib/googletest/)
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})

set(TEST_SOURCE_FILES runAllTests.cpp Resourcetests.cpp)
add_executable(runAllTests ${TEST_SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(runAllTests gtest gtest_main core)
```

The I wrote a test in the file ResourceTests.cpp and when I build the Google Test configuration, I get [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wts4.png).

What is incorrenct?

Comment: You set `TEST_SOURCE_FILES` variable, but use `SOURCE_TEST_FILES` one. Also, you set `gtest_SOURCE_DIR,` (with comma at the end), which is not what you want.

Comment: @Tsyvarev hanks a lot, I updated the question with your suggestions, but now when I build the project, I get [new errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wts4.png).

Comment: Please, add error message into the question post **as text**, not as image, This is a requirement of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry, but errors lines were too much. Anyway I found that googletest and qt are not compatible so i decided to use QtTest

Comment: Qt and googletest are compatible!